# NAS web server with Ubuntu server or similar

Tags: ubuntu, nas

I would like to build a small home server where can I access my files from everywhere including some personal web apps and my svn/git repos.

The problem is that I really don't have much space for a full computer tower, and I wonder if there is any Network Attach Storage (NAS) device I can use and install Ubuntu server on it.

I don't need much hd space (500gb should be enough) and it should have the least energy consumption possible. Wake on Lan feature would be nice.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If physical space is your problem, you can get a mini PC (plenty of those around). 
But for your needs, almost any NAS will do. You don't need to install Ubuntu. Almost all of them (I have a D-Link 323) allow web access.